# Magento - Hide link in main menu for logged in users

Tags: magento, menu, hyperlink

I am trying to modify my main navigation menu.

In the menu for guest I have a link (category) called "Log in". But after the custommer is logged in I want to change the name from "Log In" to "Shop".

I searched all over the place. I hope this is posible by modifying my local.xml file vut any solution would do.

Comment: You would have to look into the XML that defines your menu (as well as the classes involved) to find out if you can remove the link via xml. `<customer_logged_in>` and `<customer_logged_out>` are the xml update handles to nest your layout updates in, provided that the menu block has means of adding/removing links via xml.

Comment: Hi Jason. I doubd it if the menu can be updated by XML. I found the blockname. This is: "custommenu/toggle" but I already tried something like:
<customer_logged_in>
  <reference name="custommenu/toggle"> 
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/url/getCheckoutUrl"/></action>
  </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

Comment: The above does not seem to work...but I am also lost how to find classes for the individual menu links. All help is appriciated!

Comment: is "custommenu/toggle" the `name=` or `type=`? The class the block uses would be the `type=`. In the case of `type="catalog/product"`, the class would be based off the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php`. Class files also can come from the `app/code/local/` and `app/code/community` folders. The reason why `method="addLink"` works on certain blocks is because it's defined in their class. Then a template file calls the links by the defined method (i.e. `$this->getLinks()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to detect if you are logged in, you can call this function:

```
$this->helper(‘customer’)->isLoggedIn()
```

Where you have your code displaying the the login and place it in an if condition

```
if($this->helper(‘customer’)->isLoggedIn()){
//your shop code here.
} else {
//keep login code here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So I have to place this directly in the template file? Or do I have to enter this code somewhere else?

Thank you so much!

Comment: To be more clear in this case. It is not a fully php menu. It is a plugin called "responsive menu" - found here (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-menu.html). And I use categories as menu items.

Comment: Thanks! This code put me in the right direction!! The blow code solved my problem. A update trought XML would be nices but adding this in the PHP file is a good workaround. Thanks!

<?php
    if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
        echo "<div class='menu'><div class='parentMenu menu101'><a href='/index.php/login.html'><span>Shop</span></a></div></div>";
    } else { 
        echo "<div class='menu'><div class='parentMenu menu101'><a href='/index.php/login.html'><span>Log In</span></a></div></div>";
    }?>

Answer (score 0):

Added something to it I always use:

```
<?php $session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend') ); ?>
<?php if ($session->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Where should I add this code?

Answer (score 0):

in customer.xml

```
<default>
     <reference name="top.links">
     </reference>
</default>
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Shop</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Shop</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

delete the content from default. as i did above